# How to add a calculated column using conditions in a query in MS Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have two tables and from that I am generating a query. I have columns in my query with field type yes/no. These are basically columns to determine the race of a person. The user enters information in yes/no for various races. I want another calculated column in the query which checks for all other race columns and calculates values in it.

I have to check for a few conditions in for the values in columns 
For example:

1) If Hispanic is chosen, the new column should say hispanic(no matter what other options are selected. This is like a trump card)

2) If more than one is selected, then new column entry should say "multi"

3) If none of the options are selected, it should say "unknown"

4) If exactly one of them is selected, then that race should be displayed

Can anyone help me with this? I am new to Access

Comment: As for your question, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! I have tried using iff function but I am not sure how I should be using it

Comment: Sorry! i had the conditions wrong. The actual conditions are simple:
1) If Hispanic is chosen, the new column should say hispanic(no matter what other options are selected. This is like a trump card)
2) If more than one is selected, then new column entry should say "multi"
3) If none of the options are selected, it should say "unknown"
4) If exactly one of them is selected, then that race should be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't code it for you but I can point you in the right direction. What you want to do is take all the tests you explained above and put them in a coded format :

```
iif ( condition, value_if_true, value_if_false )
```

Since you have a lot of possible outputs i'd use something like a `Case Statement` where you can test for all the possibilities.

Follow [this link](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/case.php) if you need any info on how to code both type of statements (`iif` and `case`).
 
Once you have tried something like this, you can comeback with a specific question if you encountered a problem in the process.

Good luck with your database.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand how these statements work, I'm just wondering how I should incorporate those conditions in a query. If you could show one example, it'll be really helpful

Comment: I have used the iif case and got the results for conditions 1,3 and 4. I'm facing trouble with the multi option. Since I'll have to put in a condition for all possible combinations (or maybe use an or statement wisely). But I'm not able to understand how I could code the multi condition. Little help with this please!

Comment: http://www.experiglot.com/2006/12/11/how-to-use-nested-if-statements-in-excel-with-and-or-not/

Comment: DANG! I can use the last else statement to have the multi condition!!! But the problem now is that I have the 1024 character limit on my expression for the column! How do I work around it??